# Color transition stutters whenever applied to a floating image

Tags: html, performance, css, css-transitions

I've got some code that looks roughly like this, creating a hyperlink out of an image and some text:

```
<div>
  <a class="stutter" href="#">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zLg1Z2E.png" />
    <p>Label</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Using CSS like this to effect a nice color change when the user hovers over the link:

```
a {
  color: #c60;
  transition: color 1s;
}
a:hover {
  color: #d70;
}
```

Additionally, the image and p tag are both floating left.

The problem is, the transition is not smooth at all, it stutters significantly.  I've found two ways to make the stuttering stop.  First, if I remove the `float` attribute on the image, the stuttering stops and the transition is smooth.  Second, if I change the CSS selectors from `a` to `a p` and from `a:hover` to `a:hover p`, the stuttering also stops.

I'm not entirely happy with either of those, because I'd like to use `float` for layout, and it seems odd to specify the `p` element in the selector, since I want all text inside the `a` tag to change color, whether it's in a `p` tag or not.

(Frankly, this is why I try to avoid writing programs that target the Browser Virtual Machine in the first place, it always has strange glitches and slownesses that I cannot easily diagnose or fix.).

Is there any reason this stuttering would be expected behavior?

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BmovZE

Tested on Firefox 56.0.2.

EDIT: Installed chromium and tested there, no stuttering.  I'll probably delete this question and go file a Firefox bug.

EDIT 2: Submitted a bug report to Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1413822

Contrary to what I said in EDIT, I'll leave this question up and let it serve as a warning to others.  (Unless I get a bunch of downvotes :P)

Comment: Good find. Good analysis.

Comment: I don't know If I understood correctly but if by stuttering you mean the transition not being smooth is because animation-timing-function is by default ease and not linear. If you would change it to linear then you would have "smooth transition"

Comment: @Kushtrim Nah, it's the framerate, not the interpolation function.